# iOS: How to get install referrer source

Tags: ios, ios8

I want to find out how the user installed the app using what source (attribution).

For Android, it's possible to get the referrer's URL, but I haven't found an obvious way for iOS. There are external services such as AppsFlyer (http://support.appsflyer.com/entries/69796693-Accessing-AppsFlyer-Attribution-Conversion-Data-from-the-SDK-Deferred-Deep-linking-) that let's you do this.

I noticed that starting iOS 8, developers could append the publisher id and the campaign id to the App Store URL for iTunes Connect Analytics (http://www.applift.com/blog/new-era-attribution-analytics.html). Is it possible to get the campaign id and the publisher id inside the app? I couldn't find any API changes or resources on this.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I work on and maintain https://branch.io which is a free alternative to AppsFlyer with a bunch more features focused on deep linking. It will allow you to do this simply.

Comment: any update? Is it still not possible for iOS?

Answer (score 3):

This has to be solved/implemented by Apple.  If another company is coming out and saying they can solve this (Branch, etc.), they aren't being completely truthful.

The issue is that iTunes doesn't pass a referrer into the app, so without passing them the iOS IDFA on the click (redirect or out-of-bounds) every tracking method has to rely on Fingerprinting which drops off in attribution accuracy significantly past 24 hours.

Answer (score 2):

This feature isn´t available in iTunesConnect as of yet (there´s no option for 'Analytics'). The only possibility I know is to sign up for the Affiliate Program (https://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/) and use the links generated there.

But maybe it will be available in iTC when iOS8 goes live...who knows!

And your second question: no, you can´t get the App Store URL via the iOS SDK. Apple suggests to copy it over from the AppStore in iTunes (via 'copy link'), e.g. https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/youtube/id544007664?mt=8. When you open this link via

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:]
```

iOS will automatically open the AppStore.

Comment: I edited my question to make the second question more clear.  I'm looking for campaign id and publisher id that are appended to the app store URL.

Comment: Well, I guess you can set them to whatever you want. These are only values for yourself to identify certain campaigns later on when running analysis.

Comment: any solution yet to getting the campaign id and publisher id into the ios app?

Comment: still not available ?